# Is it possible to use REST Docs, REST Assured and kotlin ktor together?

Tags: spring, kotlin, rest-assured, spring-restdocs, ktor

Info about technologies available here:

[Spring REST Docs link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/)

[Rest Assured link](http://rest-assured.io/)

[Ktor backend link](https://ktor.io/)

**Main question is:** 
Can I generate documentation with `json payloads` for *ktor* backend like I did it for *Spring* backend using *Spring Rest Docs*

*Spring Rest Docs* uses unit tests technique to generate json payload and descriptions snippets. This snippets in asciidoctor style used later for including to handwritten documentation.

Comment: I didn't try it out in a setup with Ktor, but it should work. REST-assured can be used to test any REST API and Spring REST Docs supports REST-assured. To demonstrate this, I once documented a part of GitHub's API: https://github.com/fbenz/dropwizard-restdocs-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/fbenz/resources/GitHubApiTest.java

Comment: I have a similar situation, have you found out something? I know ktor doesn't really start a real web server for its tests and it's pretty problematic to use rest assured there